# monetdb set identifier as quoted

Tags: monetdb

I want to get Identifiers with quotes in monetdb.

Say I have a Table `tableA` which has two columns `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.

I want the quote to be set dynamically. if my `ColumnA` is quoted and `columnB` is not it should add quotes for `ColumnB`.

`select "columnA", ColumnB from "tableA"` query should run as below query

`select "columnA", "columnB" from "tableA"` in monet db

I have a scenario where I am getting the dynamic queries.
for some identifier (Column name) we are getting as quoted and some are not.
I want to make it unified. like those columns names are not quoted it should add qoute for them in monetdb

Exmaple
select "tableA".ColumnnameA, tableA.ColumnB from "tableA" 
when  I will execute the above query I will get the error  no such column 'tableA.ColumnB'
but when I will ad the quote to the second column table name it works fine

select "tableA".ColumnnameA, "tableA".ColumnB from "tableA" 
this query work for me but I can't add manually quote to the all the query. Is there are property which I can set in the monetDB to add quote whenever it is missing.

Can I implement the same in monetDB?

Comment: more desription:

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible in MonetDB, or -- I expect -- in any other SQL database.

The reason is that the SQL standard defines SQL to be case insensitive, so the identifiers `foo`, `Foo`, `fOo` and `FOO` are considered the same.  However, inside double quotes strange characters are allowed and case matters, so `"foo"`, `"Foo"`, `"fOo"` and `"FOO"` are distinct.

In fact, MonetDB maps `foo`, `Foo`, `fOo` and `FOO` all to `"foo"`, as you can see in the following example:

```
sql>create table foo(i int, "J" int);
create table foo(i int, "J" int);
operation successful (8.551ms)
sql>select i from foo;
select i from foo;
+---+
| i |
+===+
+---+
0 tuples (1.464ms)
sql>select "i" from foo;
select "i" from foo;
+---+
| i |
+===+
+---+
0 tuples (2.686ms)
sql>select "I" from foo;
SELECT: identifier 'I' unknown
```

so, to wrap up, you're best off either

a) quoting all column names, making sure to get upper/lower case right, or

b) not quoting any column names so case doesn't matter.

When in doubt I'd pick option (a) as it's probably most future proof.

Joeri